# Fragment-scoped ObjectGraph

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I learned how to create `Application`-scoped `ObjectGraph`, and `@Inject` into my `View`s from it.

Then I learned how to create `Activity`-scoped `ObjectGraph`, and `@Inject` into my `View`'s from an `Activity`'s `Context`.

Now I need to learn how to create a `Fragment`-scoped `ObjectGraph`, since `Fragment` is not a `Context` and is not injected into my `View`s by the `LayoutInflater`.

As I see the problem: I need a way to reference a `Fragment` from inside a `View`, but I think this is essentially wrong, and I need another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Mortar for that https://github.com/square/mortar